# RPostgreSQL- Insert a column into another table according to the ID

Tags: r, rpostgresql

I've used RPostgreSQL to connect R and postgresQL, and I'd like to insert a column into another table according to the "pid", please advise how is can be achieved using R command:

```
>library(RPostgreSQL)
>drv<-dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
>itemlist<- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from project_budget_itemlist")
>View(itemlist)
 pid item cost
  1   ABC  9
  2   ACB  8
  3   BAC  7
  3   ZZZ  6
```

and another tables is as follow:

```
  >name<- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from namelist")
  >View(name)

  pid name 
   1  Sally
   2  Joy
   3  Susan
```

I want to the result to be:

```
   pid item cost name 
    1   ABC  9   Sally
    2   ACB  8   Joy
    3   BAC  7   Susan
    3   ZZZ  6   Susan
```

Comment: Maybe `?merge` ? (You want a dataset with the expected result or to write the expected result back in postgres ?)

Comment: @Tensibai: Hi, no need to return the result in postgres. I just want the combination and do some plot.

Comment: In this case `merge(itemlist,name)` should do ...

Comment: Thanks, but it seems in vail and the merged table is empty.

Comment: I've no idea, this works fine with data frames created with your question example... maybe you can `dput(itemlist)` and `dput(name)` so I can try on the same type of data

Comment: The data type is data frames as well, and the error message is :Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no matching pids in both outputs, the merge will return an empty data frame.  If there are, then this should work:

```
merge(itemList, name)
```